# divide bags of candies among three children evenly

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

I have `n` bags of candies such that no two bags have the same number of candies inside (i.e. it's a set `A[] = {a0,a1,a2,...,ai,...,aj}` where `ai != aj`).

I know how many candies is in each bag and the total number `M` of candies I have.

I need to divide the bags among three children so that the candies are distributed as fairly as possible (i.e. each child gets as close to `M/3` as possible).

Needless to say, I may not tear into the bags to even out the counts -- then the question would be trivial.

Does anyone have any thoughts how to solve this -- preferably in Java?

EDIT:

the interviewer wanted me to use a 2-D array to solve the problem: the first kid gets x, the second kid y, the third gets the rest: `S[x][y]`.

This after I tried following:

```
1] sort array n lg n
2] starting with largest remaining bag, give bag to kid with fewest candy.
```

---

Here is my solution for partitioning to two children (it is the correct answer). Maybe it will help with getting the 3-way partition.

```
int evenlyForTwo(int[] A, int M) {
    boolean[] S = new boolean[M+1];
    S[0]=true;//empty set
    for(int i=0; i<A.length; i++)
        for(int x=M; x >= A[i]; x--)
            if(!S[x])
                S[x]=S[x-A[i]];
    int k = (int) M/2;
    while(!S[k])
        k--;
    return k;//one kid gets k the other the rest.
}//
```

Comment: Are the kids of roughly equal physical stature? Also, are we assuming that they are rational beings (except when it comes to health issues) with the goal of consuming as much candy as possible?

Comment: Ask one kid to split up the candies, then each kid gets to pick their bag.  The kid that did the splitting picks last.  Of course that's not in Java though :)

Comment: This is the 3-partition problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), which is NP-hard.

Comment: There is always the option of brute force. No one said anything about performance.

Comment: @Keith +1, and here's the direct link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem.  Some of the (NP) solutions or (P) approximate solutions for the subset-sum or partition problems may be helpful.

Comment: @erikxiv: I agree.  Just wanted to add that info to the discussion.

Comment: @Keith Randall, the interviewer wanted me to use a 2-D array to solve the problem. I am editing to add that note.

Comment: `S[x][y]`? How does this work? Don't you mean `S[x][y]` where the first child is `x=0` and the second is `x=1` and `y` the bags they have each?

Comment: @Yanick Rochon, I am not sure. Maybe `boolean S[][] = new boolean[M+1][M+1]` where `M` is the total number of candies.

Comment: @erikxiv, we must use dynamic-programming

Comment: @kasavbere, `S[M][M]:boolean` seems like a waste, when all you need is `S[2][N]:boolean`

Comment: I have edited to show solution for 2-way partition; maybe that will help with 3-way solution.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you describe is known as the [3-Partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem) and is known to be NP-hard. The problem is discussed a bit on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82332/seeking-a-solution-algorithm-to-the-3-partition-problem). You might find some of the pointers there of some value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little solution, crude but gives correct results. And you can even change the number of children, bags, etc.

```
public class BagOfCandies {

   static public void main(String...args) {
      int repeat = 10;
      int childCount = 3;
      int bagsCount = childCount + (int) (Math.random() * 10);

      for (int k=0; k<repeat; k++) {
         int candyCount = 0, n=0;
         int[] bags = new int[bagsCount];
         for (int i=0; i<bags.length; i++) {
            n += 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 2);
            bags[i] = n;
            candyCount += n;
         }
         shuffle(bags);   // completely optional! It works regardless

         boolean[][] dist = divideBags(bags, childCount);

         System.out.println("Bags of candy : " + Arrays.toString(bags) + " = " + bags.length);
         System.out.println("Total calculated candies is " + candyCount);
         int childCandySum = 0;
         for (int c=0; c<childCount; c++) {
            int childCandies = countSumBags(bags, dist[c]);
            System.out.println("Child " + (c+1) + " = " + childCandies + " --> " + Arrays.toString(dist[c]));
            childCandySum += childCandies;
         }
         System.out.println("For a total of " + childCandySum + " candies");
         System.out.println("----------------");
      }
   }

   static private void shuffle(int[] bags) {
      for (int i=0, len=bags.length; i<len; i++) {
         int a = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*len);
         int b = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*len);
         int v = bags[a];
         bags[a] = bags[b];
         bags[b] = v;
      }
   }

   static private boolean[][] divideBags(int[] bags, int childCount) {
      int bagCount = bags.length;

      boolean[][] dist = new boolean[childCount][bagCount];
      for (int c=0; c<childCount; c++) 
         Arrays.fill(dist[c], false);

      for (int i=0; i<bagCount; i+=childCount)
         for (int j=i, c=0; c<childCount && j<bagCount; j++, c++)
            dist[c][j] = true;

      if (childCount == 1) return dist;  // shortcut here

      int sumDiff = 1;
      int oldDiff = 0;

      while (sumDiff != oldDiff) {
         oldDiff = sumDiff;
         sumDiff = 0;

         // start comparing children in pair
         for (int child1=0; child1<childCount-1; child1++) {
            for (int child2=child1+1; child2<childCount; child2++) {

               int count1 = countSumBags(bags, dist[child1]);
               int count2 = countSumBags(bags, dist[child2]);
               int diff = Math.abs(count1 - count2);

               // a difference less than 2 is negligeable
               if (diff > 1) {
                  // find some bags with can swap to even their difference
                  int c1=-1, c2=-1, cdiff;
                  boolean swap = false;

                  for (int i=0; i<bagCount-1; i++) {
                     for (int j=i; j<bagCount; j++) {
                        if (dist[child1][i] && dist[child2][j]) {
                           cdiff = Math.abs((count1 - bags[i] + bags[j]) - (count2 + bags[i] - bags[j]));
                           if (cdiff < diff) {
                              c1 = i; c2 = j;
                              diff = cdiff;
                              swap = true;
                           }
                        }
                        if (dist[child1][j] && dist[child2][i]) {
                           cdiff = Math.abs((count1 - bags[j] + bags[i]) - (count2 + bags[j] - bags[i]));
                           if (cdiff < diff) {
                              c1 = j; c2 = i;
                              diff = cdiff;
                              swap = true;
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }

                  if (swap) {
                     //System.out.println("Swaping " + c1 + " with " + c2);
                     dist[child1][c1] = false; dist[child1][c2] = true;
                     dist[child2][c1] = true;  dist[child2][c2] = false;
                  }
               }

               //System.out.println("Diff between " + child1 + "(" + countSumBags(bags, dist[child1]) + ") and " + child2 + "(" + countSumBags(bags, dist[child2]) + ") is " + diff);

               sumDiff += diff;
            }
         }

         //System.out.println("oldDiff="+oldDiff+", sumDiff="+sumDiff);
      }

      return dist;
   }

   static private int countSumBags(int[] bags, boolean[] t) {
      int count = 0;
      for (int i=0; i<t.length; i++) {
         if (t[i]) {
            count+=bags[i];
         }
      }
      return count;
   }

}
```

I don't know if this the result you were looking for, but it seems to be, from my understanding of the question.